# Match specific column with grep command

Tags: linux, grep, match

I am having trouble matching specific column with grep command. I have a test file (test.txt) like this..

```
Bra001325       835     T       13      c$c$c$c$c$cccccCcc      !!!!!68886676
Bra001325       836     C       8       ,,,,,.,,        68886676
Bra001325       841     A       6       ,$,.,,. BJJJJE
Bra001325       866     C       2       ,.      HJ
```

And i want to extract all those lines which has a number `866` in the second column. When i use `grep` command i am getting all the lines that contains the number that number

```
grep "866" test.txt

Bra001325       835     T       13      c$c$c$c$c$cccccCcc      !!!!!68886676
Bra001325       836     C       8       ,,,,,.,,        68886676
Bra001325       866     C       2       ,.      HJ
```

How can i match specific column with grep command?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
$ awk '$2 == 866' test.txt
```

No need to add `{print}`, the default behaviour of `awk` is to print on a `true` condition.

with [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) :

```
$ grep -P '^\S+\s+866\b' *
```

But [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) can print filenames too & is quite more robust than [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) here :

```
$ awk '$2 == 866{print FILENAME":"$0; nextfile}' *
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering is there a way do with `grep`? I ask this because i have many files and when i try to use `awk` it just prints the lines which matches the pattern in those files. However with `grep` you will get the file name followed by the line that matches the pattern.

Comment: Corrected typo in grep

Comment: Oh cool. I guess i should have seen that typo. May be this is not important but i wanted to match `866` and not `836`.

Comment: `grep` will fail if there are `866` with space around elsewhere in the line other than field 2.  `awk` is the best here.

Comment: What's the delimiter awk uses by-default and how can we change it ?

Comment: @MohitVerma awk uses spaces by default, to change to use e.g. commas, use  "awk -F," but be careful when using shell-significant characters like '|^$:' etc.  Best to single quote like "awk -F'|'"

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the field separator is not space but comma. So I would have to add this, otherwise it won't work for me (On ubuntu 18.04.1).

```
awk -F ', ' '$2 == 866' test.txt
```